# How to bulk update (delete) Product Variations

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to bulk select **product variations for deletion**, just like we can do with content and products in admin.

I tried to duplicate the products admin view, and also creating my own, both throw various error pages. It seems there is a security system in place to prevent variation deletion outside of the product pages?

Is there any way to accomplish this?

This is error I get if I add and use a bulk update field (the view is getting "product variations")

[image]

```
    The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function getPlugin() on null in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\BulkForm->viewsFormSubmit() (line 372 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/BulkForm.php).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems now you know the answer :)

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bulk/issues/3023651

BTW, thank you for your contribution to the module!